# How do you get the name of a service in kernel mode? (Windows)

Tags: windows, service, windows-7, drivers, kernel-mode

I am hooking the SSDT of Windows 7 x64 (I already hooked it correctly and such - that's not the problem.) to bypass a certain Anti-Cheat for a game.

The problem: Trying to get the exe name is of no use since it always outputs svchost.exe for Windows services, and since the anticheat is doing it's work in a service I can't correctly "guess" which svchost.exe is the Anti-Cheat.

The (pseudo-)code:

`NTSTATUS newOpenProcess(ProcessHandle, DesiredAccess, ObjectAttributes, ClientId)
{
     if(ClientId points to our game) // checks name of process to be opened
         DbgPrint("%s", PsGetProcessImageFileName(PsGetCurrentProcess())); // svchost.exe - NEED THE SERVICE NAME
     return oldOpenProcess(ProcessHandle, DesiredAccess, ObjectAttributes, ClientId);
}`

Please note: THIS IS NOT FOR ANYTHING BUT LEARNING PURPOSES. This is not for malware or anything of the such; it is not illegal!

Comment: A few ideas: `svchost.exe` works by loading a DLL for the service it is to run, so if you can enumerate the modules for each instance of `svchost.exe` you can identify the right one that way.  Or you could look for the process that has the DLL file open.  Or if you can get a user-mode process to do the work for you, you could use QueryServiceStatusEx to get the process ID.

Comment: Is this article of any help? http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=472

It uses ZwQueryInformationProcess which gives you much better information (such as full path - as seen in the article).

Comment: That would probably be perfect if I were to attempt to write a driver again. Thanks for the link! Feel free to post it as an answer and i will accept it.